# Bootstrap 3, open Collapse element on hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to convert some code from `Bootstrap 2` to `Bootstrap 3`:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        href, target = $this.attr('data-target') || e.preventDefault() || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '') //strip for ie7
        ,
        option = $(target).data('collapse') ? 'show' : $this.data()
        $(target).collapse(option)
});
```

It looks like they changed quite a bit of stuff around from `v2 > v3`,so I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to change. I found a thread that kinda deals with it, but doesn't  actually do what I'm after:

[Bootstrap Collapse accordion on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719931/bootstrap-collapse-accordion-on-hover)

Basically I need to have x elements in the `Collapse`. When you hover over one of them, it will open it up (instead of having to click it). Then when you move over another one, it will close the others and open the new one.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i edited the script as followed to put it to work

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('mouseenter.collapse', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            href, target = $this.attr('data-target') || e.preventDefault() || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')
            ,
            option = $(target).hasClass('in') ? 'hide' : "show";
            $('.panel-collapse').not(target).collapse("hide");
            $(target).collapse(option);
    })
});
```

Comment: when i hover first times all open then work very well. how to fix this one