# Bootstrap accordion open on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I already tried other examples that I found from Google and SO but can get any to execute so I was trying this silly solution for opening the Bootstrap accordion on hover but it doesn't want to work either...  any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
<nav class="nav">
<ul>
<li><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-trigger="hover" data-parent="#submenu" href="#one">SHOW</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>


<div id="one" class="collapse">
<div class="accordion-inner">
HERE IS THE STUFF
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#submenu').collapse({ trigger: "hover" })
```

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/5J852/

Comment: Have you seen this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719931/bootstrap-collapse-accordion-on-hover ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".accordion-toggle" ).mouseover(function(){
    $( ".accordion-toggle" ).trigger( "click" );
    // If creating multiple accordion items, use the below to prevent all other
    // items with the class "accordion-toggle" triggering a click event
    // $(this).trigger("click");
  });
});
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5J852/24/)

Comment: This does answers my question, but I would need the 'accordion' to close automatically if I leave either the 'li' or the 'hidden accordion' area.. anything you might think of to solve that?

Comment: aaaah what I am looking for is actually a dropdown menu.. . thank you anyway

Comment: happy to know that my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

i Guess this is a dirty way to do it..

http://jsfiddle.net/5J852/16/

by already using the built in event trigger

```
$('.nav a').mouseover(function(){
    $( this ).click();
});
$('.nav a').mouseout(function(){
    $( this ).click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps

```
$('.accordion-toggle').hover(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5J852/4/