# Bootstrap collapse open on mouse enter close on mouse leave

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My goal is using bootstrap to to make a group of collapse button that that extend when cursor is on then and collapse when cursor leave them. It can be only one open collapse. My code is working with one button but when i do over button with cursor fast first two (button 1 and button 2) are still open and last one ( button 3 ) works fine ( it open and then close). I use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23406565/2328930) to implement my code. Can someone help me to fix it? Here is a link to [JSIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6s06tvq4/2/). Here is my JQuery code:

```
$('.row .collapse-container').on('mouseenter', function(e){
    $textHolder = $('.text-container', this)[0];

    $($textHolder).queue(function(){
        $($textHolder).collapse('show');
        if (!$($textHolder).hasClass('collapsing')){
            $(this).dequeue();      
        }
    })
    if (!$($textHolder).hasClass('collapsing')){
        $($textHolder).dequeue();
    }
})
$('.row .collapse-container').on('mouseleave', function(e){
    $textHolder = $('.text-container', this)[0];
    $($textHolder).queue(function(){
    $($textHolder).collapse('hide');
        if (!$($textHolder).hasClass('collapsing')){
            $(this).dequeue();      
        }
    })
    if (!$($textHolder).hasClass('collapsing')){
        $($textHolder).dequeue();
    }
})
$('.row').on('shown.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', '.text-container', function(e) {
    $(this).dequeue();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After i let it sleep, I get a solution, that works in 99% in my tests. Only case that is not working is when I enter a element while collapsing animation is running. But that is the best that I can do for now. Here is my solution if anyone else thing that is good enough to use it. Or if can make it work in 100% will be great. Here is a link to [JSIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6s06tvq4/3/), and jQuery code:

```
$('.row .collapse-container').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    $textHolder = $('.text-container', this)[0];

    $($textHolder).queue(function () {
        $($textHolder).collapse('show');
    })
    if (!$($textHolder).hasClass('collapsing')) {
        $($textHolder).dequeue();
    }
})
$('.row .collapse-container').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    $textHolder = $('.text-container', this)[0];
    if ($($textHolder).hasClass('collapsing')) {
        $($textHolder).queue(function () {
            $(this).collapse('hide');
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    }else{
        $($textHolder).collapse('hide');
    }
})
$('.row').on('shown.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', '.text-container', function (e) {
    $(this).dequeue();
});
```